# Implementing internationalization (language strings) in a PHP application

Tags: php, internationalization, globalization, icu

I want to build a CMS that can handle fetching locale strings to support internationalization. I plan on storing the strings in a database, and then placing a key/value cache like memcache in between the database and the application to prevent performance drops for hitting the database each page for a translation.

This is more complex than using PHP files with arrays of strings - but that method is incredibly inefficient when you have 2,000 translation lines.

I thought about using [gettext](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php), but I'm not sure that users of the CMS will be comfortable working with the gettext files. If the strings are stored in a database, then a nice administration system can be setup to allow them to make changes whenever they want and the caching in RAM will insure that the fetching of those strings is as fast, or faster than gettext. I also don't feel safe using the PHP extension considering [not even the zend framework uses it](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.adapter.html#zend.translate.adapter.gettext).

Is there anything wrong with this approach?

### Update

I thought perhaps I would add more food for thought. One of the problems with string translations it is that they doesn't support dates, money, or conditional statements. However, thanks to [intl](https://www.php.net/intl) PHP now has [MessageFormatter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/messageformatter.formatmessage.php) which is what really needs to be used anyway.

```
// Load string from gettext file
$string = _("{0} resulted in {1,choice,0#no errors|1#single error|1<{1, number} errors}");

// Format using the current locale
msgfmt_format_message(setlocale(LC_ALL, 0), $string, array('Update', 3));
```

On another note, one of the things I don't like about gettext is that the text is embedded into the application all over the place. That means that the team responsible for the primary translation (usually English) has to have access to the project source code to make changes in all the places the default statements are placed. It's almost as bad as applications that have SQL spaghetti-code all over.

So, it makes sense to use keys like `_('error.404_not_found')` which then allow the content writers and translators to just worry about the PO/MO files without messing in the code.

However, in the event that a gettext translation *doesn't exist* for the given key then there is no way to fall back to a default (like you could with a custom handler). This means that you either have the writter mucking around in your code - or have "error.404_not_found" shown to users that don't have a locale translation!

In addition, I am not aware of any large projects which use PHP's gettext. I would appreciate any links to *well-used* (and therefore tested), systems which actually rely on the native PHP gettext extension.

Comment: The new ICU library seems promising, haven't used yet. But as you already noticed, gettext is installed in almos any PHP installation out there, while the ICU lib requires PHP 5.3+ and the extension enabled (read shred host will show the "error.404_not_found" string).

I would stick with gettext for now.

Comment: It's not just that the ICU library seems promising, it's that there is no way to do proper translations *without it*. gettext or not, the intl classes are needed for building proper phrases with times, currency, or plural phrase choices.

Comment: Yes you can, take a look at WordPress gettext implementation. http://codex.wordpress.org/I18n_for_WordPress_Developers

Comment: @xmarcos, if you are talking about wordpress `_n()` function - that only works with one singular/plural form. There are some languages that have more than just two forms. Only MessageFormatter supports those (rough example shown above).

Comment: I'm talking that it can be done, `_n()` is just and example on how you can use the tools. Gettext is a mature, powerful, widely tested and very well supported tool. you came here asking for a recommendation, i recommend that one.

Comment: The ICU library, on the other hand, may be a good replacement in the future, but just now is not widely adopted, has lack of support (due to the first fact) is not mature nor very well tested and has no fallback support out-of-the box.

Comment: @xmarcos, gettext is not a competitor to the ICU library - **they both do different things**. So gettext aside, there is no way to do what MessageFormatter does without re-inventing the entire intl library all over again. I would say that the ICU library is more important to an application that gettext simply because there are alternatives to gettext while there are none (but a couple very-incomplete attempts like `_n()`) to the ICU classes.

Comment: Actually, it seems that gettext [does support multiple plural forms](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#Plural-forms). However, it still can't handle numbers, times, [or other aspects of translation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html#aspects) that the ICU tackles.

Comment: you might wanna read [this][1] and [this][2]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185568/alternatives-to-gettext
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2275270/whats-the-simplest-php-alternative-to-the-php-gettext-extension-which-can-be-su

Comment: Please note!! On ANOTHER note, ChoiceFormat is officially deprecated in favor of plural format. http://bugs.icu-project.org/trac/ticket/8788 I don't want to get booted for linkspam but follow the links in the ticket and also use http://demo.icu-project.org/icu4jweb/formatTest.jsp to try out plural formats on the fly

Comment: You would write your message using plural format thusly:    "{0} resulted in {1,plural,=0 {no errors} one{a single error} other{# errors}}"   and translators for each language could use plural rules as shown in the following link and they would operate properly for languages, see http://unicode.org/repos/cldr-tmp/trunk/diff/supplemental/language_plural_rules.html

Answer (score 6):

Gettext uses a binary protocol that is quite quick. Also the gettext implementation is usually simpler as it only requires `echo _('Text to translate');`. It also has existing tools for translators to use and they're proven to work well.

You can store them in a database but I feel it would be slower and a bit overkill, especially since you'd have to build the system to edit the translations yourself.

If only you could actually cache the lookups in a dedicated memory portion in APC, you'd be golden. Sadly, I don't know how.

Comment: I updated my question and I'm wondering if you could address the question I raised?

Comment: WordPress uses gettext. It's the biggest project I can think of in terms of number of sites powered by it as well as the user base. As for dealing with non-existent translations... There's no rule that says you have to use the built-in `_()` function (and kin). You can write your own functions that wrap those, test for existence of a translation (if the returned translation is the same as the key), and even do caching in memcache.

Answer (score 5):

For those that are interested, it seems full support for [locales](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) and i18n in PHP is finally starting to take place.

```
// Set the current locale to the one the user agent wants
$locale = Locale::acceptFromHttp(getenv('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'));

// Default Locale
Locale::setDefault($locale);
setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale . '.UTF-8');

// Default timezone of server
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

// iconv encoding
iconv_set_encoding("internal_encoding", "UTF-8");

// multibyte encoding
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
```

There are several things that need to be condered and detecting the timezone/locale and then using it to correctly parse and display input and output is important. There is a [PHP I18N library](https://github.com/dotroll/I18N) that was just released which contains lookup tables for much of this information.

Processing User input is important to make sure you application has clean, well-formed UTF-8 strings from whatever input the user enters. [iconv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) is great for this.

```
/**
 * Convert a string from one encoding to another encoding
 * and remove invalid bytes sequences.
 *
 * @param string $string to convert
 * @param string $to encoding you want the string in
 * @param string $from encoding that string is in
 * @return string
 */
function encode($string, $to = 'UTF-8', $from = 'UTF-8')
{
    // ASCII is already valid UTF-8
    if($to == 'UTF-8' AND is_ascii($string))
    {
        return $string;
    }

    // Convert the string
    return @iconv($from, $to . '//TRANSLIT//IGNORE', $string);
}


/**
 * Tests whether a string contains only 7bit ASCII characters.
 *
 * @param string $string to check
 * @return bool
 */
function is_ascii($string)
{
    return ! preg_match('/[^\x00-\x7F]/S', $string);
}
```

Then just run the input through these functions.

```
$utf8_string = normalizer_normalize(encode($_POST['text']), Normalizer::FORM_C);
```

#### Translations

As Andre said, It seems [gettext](http://php.net/gettext) is the smart default choice for writing applications that can be translated.

1. Gettext uses a binary protocol that is quite quick.
2. The gettext implementation is usually simpler as it only requires `_('Text to translate')`
3. Existing tools for translators to use and they're proven to work well.

When you reach facebook size then you can work on implementing RAM-cached, alternative methods like the one I mentioned in the question. However, nothing beats "simple, fast, and works" for most projects.

However, there are also addition things that gettext cannot handle. Things like displaying dates, money, and numbers. For those you need the [INTL extionsion](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php).

```
/**
 * Return an IntlDateFormatter object using the current system locale
 *
 * @param string $locale string
 * @param integer $datetype IntlDateFormatter constant
 * @param integer $timetype IntlDateFormatter constant
 * @param string $timezone Time zone ID, default is system default
 * @return IntlDateFormatter
 */
function __date($locale = NULL, $datetype = IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM, $timetype = IntlDateFormatter::SHORT, $timezone = NULL)
{
    return new IntlDateFormatter($locale ?: setlocale(LC_ALL, 0), $datetype, $timetype, $timezone);
}

$now = new DateTime();
print __date()->format($now);
$time = __date()->parse($string);
```

In addition you can use [strftime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) to parse dates taking the current locale into consideration.

Sometimes you need the values for numbers and dates inserted correctly into locale messages

```
/**
 * Format the given string using the current system locale
 * Basically, it's sprintf on i18n steroids.
 *
 * @param string $string to parse
 * @param array $params to insert
 * @return string
 */
function __($string, array $params = NULL)
{
    return msgfmt_format_message(setlocale(LC_ALL, 0), $string, $params);
}

// Multiple choices (can also just use ngettext)
print __(_("{1,choice,0#no errors|1#single error|1<{1, number} errors}"), array(4));

// Show time in the correct way
print __(_("It is now {0,time,medium}), time());
```

See the [ICU format details](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classMessageFormat.html#details) for more information.

#### Database

Make sure your connection to the database is using the correct charset so that nothing gets currupted on storage.

#### String Functions

You need to understand the difference between the [string](http://us.php.net/strlen), [mb_string](https://www.php.net/mb_string), and [grapheme functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.intl.grapheme.php).

```
// 'LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH RING ABOVE' (U+00E5) normalization form "D"
$char_a_ring_nfd = "a\xCC\x8A";

var_dump(grapheme_strlen($char_a_ring_nfd));
var_dump(mb_strlen($char_a_ring_nfd));
var_dump(strlen($char_a_ring_nfd));

// 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH RING ABOVE' (U+00C5)
$char_A_ring = "\xC3\x85";

var_dump(grapheme_strlen($char_A_ring));
var_dump(mb_strlen($char_A_ring));
var_dump(strlen($char_A_ring));
```

#### Domain name TLD's

The [IDN functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.idn-to-ascii.php) from the INTL library are a big help processing non-ascii domain names.

Comment: See my comment above ^^ ChoiceFormat is deprecated in favor of PluralFormat.

Comment: Whats the difference between `Locale::setDefault($locale);` and `setlocale(LC_ALL, $locale . '.UTF-8');`? Also where can I find a list of locale language tags?

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of other SO questions and answers similar to this one. I suggest you search and read them as well.

Advice? Use an existing solution like gettext or xliff as it will save you lot's of grief when you hit all the translation edge cases such as right to left text, date formats, different text volumes, French is 30% more verbose than English for example that screw up formatting etc. Even better advice Don't do it. If the users want to translate they will make a clone and  translate it. Because Localisation is more about look and feel and using colloquial language this is usually what happens. Again giving and example Anglo-Saxon culture likes cool web colours and san-serif type faces. Hispanic culture like bright colours and Serif/Cursive types. Which to cater for you would need different layouts per language.

Zend actually cater for the following adapters for Zend_Translate and it is a useful list.

- Array:- Use PHP arrays for Small pages; simplest usage; only for programmers
- Csv:- Use comma separated (*.csv/*.txt) files for Simple text file format; fast; possible problems with unicode characters
- Gettext:- Use binary gettext (*.mo) files for GNU standard for linux; thread-safe; needs tools for translation
- Ini:- Use simple INI (*.ini) files for Simple text file format; fast; possible problems with unicode characters
- Tbx:- Use termbase exchange (*.tbx/*.xml) files for Industry standard for inter application terminology strings; XML format
- Tmx:- Use tmx (*.tmx/*.xml) files for Industry standard for inter application translation; XML format; human readable
- Qt:- Use qt linguist (*.ts) files for Cross platform application framework; XML format; human readable
- Xliff:- Use xliff (*.xliff/*.xml) files for A simpler format as TMX but related to it; XML format; human readable
- XmlTm:- Use xmltm (*.xml) files for Industry standard for XML document translation memory; XML format; human readable
- Others:- *.sql for Different other adapters may be implemented in the future

Comment: Over the past couple years I've ready many of the questions on gettext here. However, none of them present a reasonable alternative like I gave - it's usually all nonsense like parsing a CSV/INI/JSON file into a giant array for lookups. At any rate, I'm not sure what you are talking about in your second paragraph - I don't see how gettext or arrays have trouble with rtl or ltr languages. In addition, *neither of them* support date formats or changes in presentation - that is what the intl PHP module with MessageFormatter is for.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using the ICU stuff in my framework and really finding it simple and useful to use. My system is XML-based with XPath queries and not a database as you're suggesting to use. I've not found this approach to be inefficient. I played around with Resource bundles too when researching techniques but found them quite complicated to implement.

The [Locale](http://uk.php.net/Locale) functionality is a god send. You can do so much more easily:

```
// Available translations
$languages = array('en', 'fr', 'de');

// The language the user wants
$preference = (isset($_COOKIE['lang'])) ?
    $_COOKIE['lang'] : ((isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'])) ?
        Locale::acceptFromHttp($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) : '');

// Match preferred language to those available, defaulting to generic English
$locale = Locale::lookup($languages, $preference, false, 'en');

// Construct path to dictionary file
$file = $dir . '/' . $locale . '.xsl';

// Check that dictionary file is readable
if (!file_exists($file) || !is_readable($file)) {
    throw new RuntimeException('Dictionary could not be loaded');
}

// Load and return dictionary file
$dictionary = simplexml_load_file($file);
```

I then perform word lookups using a method like this:

```
$selector = '/i18n/text[@label="' . $word . '"]';
$result = $dictionary->xpath($selector);
$text = array_shift($result);

if ($formatted && isset($text)) {
    return new MessageFormatter($locale, $text);
 }
```

The bonus for my system is that the template system is XSL-based which means I can use the same translation XML files directly in my templates for simple messages that don't need any i18n formatting.

Comment: That first snippet about selecting the right locale based on the user preference is perfect. I hope more people see this code block and implement it in their applications. However, I can't imagine the XML object is any less resource intensive than an array. The object contains additional properties that require extra memory. Still, using xpaths is an interesting idea.

Answer (score 1):

Stick with gettext, you won't find a faster alternative in PHP.

Regarding the *how*, you can use a database to store your catalog and allow other users to translate the strings using a friendly gui. When the new changes are reviewed/approved, hit a button, compile a new `.mo` file and deploy.

Some resources to get you on track:

- http://code.google.com/p/simplepo/
- http://www.josscrowcroft.com/2011/code/php-mo-convert-gettext-po-file-to-binary-mo-file-php/
- https://launchpad.net/php-gettext/
- http://sourceforge.net/projects/tcktranslator/

Comment: @Zyava, the array may be faster because it's just sitting in RAM - but fact it's sitting in RAM also the problem. Loading a CSV or INI file has the same problem because it all ends up as an array sitting in memory wasting resources.

Comment: @Zyava, faster is relative to the size of your project. Besides gettext provides may more features out of the box that plain arrays, is largely tested, supported and enabled in almost any PHP installation.

Comment: This is extension is so good that even zf doesn't use it? Sorry, but don't you feel something is wrong here?

Comment: @Zyava i guess that by zf, you mean `Zend_Translate`, which is a normalized *interface* that provides a consistent API on top of  many adapters. Not surprisingly, one of those adapters (the one Zend *recommends* for large applications) is gettext.

Comment: OP posted this [link](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.translate.adapter.html#zend.translate.adapter.gettext), please read it. In short, zf gettext adapter doesn't use php gettext extension, which "is largely tested, supported and enabled in almost any PHP installation" as you said...

Comment: It's an userland implementation of the parser, but it's gettext anyway and the one solution recommended.

They bundle it to ensure portability of the Framework, but you can easily write a `Zend_Translate_Adapter_Gettext_Native` adapter to use the php extension.

Answer (score 1):

What about csv files (which can be easily edited in many apps) and caching to memcache (wincache, etc.)? This approach works well in magento. All languages phrases in the code are wrapped into `__()` function, for example

```
<?php echo $this->__('Some text') ?>
```

Then, for example before new version release, you run simple script which parses source files, finds all text wrapped into  `__()` and puts into .csv file. You load csv files and cache them to memcache. In `__()` function you look into your memcache where translations are cached.

Comment: Magento is so large already I doubt anyone would notice the hit from using CSV. *I mean, what's another billion to the U.S. deficit of 14 trillion?*

Comment: There is no hit from using CSV, except the first time when CSV is loaded to memcache. Doesn't matter how you store you lang file, you will load it to memcache. Any other approach is slower than direct read from memcache, you know. CSV file is just the most convenient format for storing translations because any office girl can edit it.

Comment: My apologies @Zyava, I misread your comment. Yes, loading a file (CSV or whatever) and parsing the individual lines and storing them in memcache is exactly what I proposed.

Answer (score 0):

In a recent project, we considered using gettext, but it turned out to be easier to just write our own functionality. It really is quite simple: Create a JSON file per locale (e.g. strings.en.json, strings.es.json, etc.), and create a function somewhere called "translate()" or something, and then just call that. That function will determine the current locale (from the URI or a session var or something), and return the localized string.

The only thing to remember is to make sure any HTML you output is encoded in UTF-8, and marked as such in the markup (e.g. in the doctype, etc.)

Comment: Apparently you're translations are not very large - or you don't monitor memory usage. Arrays in PHP aren't free.

Comment: @Xeoncross: Very few PHP developers benchmark much at all, it is not usually the first choice for resource sensitive work.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not really an answer to your question, but maybe you can get some ideas from the Symfony translation component? It looks very good to me, although I must confess I haven't used it myself yet.

The documentation for the component can be found at

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/translation.html

and the code for the component can be found at

https://github.com/symfony/Translation.

It should be easy to use the Translation component, because Symfony components are intended to be able to be used as standalone components.

Comment: Looks about the same as Zend, however it doesn't seem to support gettext like Zend does.

Comment: Maybe you can investigate why they don't support gettext(), I can only assume they have their reasons for it. This knowledge can be relevant for you own decision.

Answer (score 0):

> On another note, one of the things I don't like about gettext is that
>   the text is embedded into the application all over the place. That
>   means that the team responsible for the primary translation (usually
>   English) has to have access to the project source code to make changes
>   in all the places the default statements are placed. It's almost as
>   bad as applications that have SQL spaghetti-code all over.

This isn't actually true. You can have a header file (sorry, ex C programmer), such as:

```
<?php
define(MSG_404_NOT_FOUND, 'error.404_not_found')
?>
```

Then whenever you want a message, use `_(MSG_404_NOT_FOUND)`. This is much more flexible than requiring developers to remember the exact syntax of the non-localised message every time they want to spit out a localised version.

You could go one step further, and generate the header file in a build step, maybe from CSV or database, and cross-reference with the translation to detect missing strings.

Comment: That is a neat idea. It tackles the problem brought up above about allowing both the "keyed" string name, as well as providing the default translation if none is found. Unfortunately, it's not realistic to imagine 2,100 defines being stored in a file. That would be too large a waste of resources.

Answer (score 0):

have a zend plugin that works very well for this.

```
<?php
/** dependencies **/
require 'Zend/Loader/Autoloader.php';
require 'Zag/Filter/CharConvert.php';

Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance()->setFallbackAutoloader(true);

//filter
$filter = new Zag_Filter_CharConvert(array(
    'replaceWhiteSpace' => '-',
    'locale' => 'en_US',
    'charset'=> 'UTF-8'
));

echo $filter->filter('ééé ááá 90');//eee-aaa-90
echo $filter->filter('óóó 10aáééé');//ooo-10aaeee
```

if you do not want to use the zend framework can only use the plugin.

hug!