# Gettext clone or alternative under permissive license (non-copyleft)?

Tags: c, gettext

At the moment I am trying to find a gettext alternative with comparable tool support. However, the library itself needs to be under a permissive license, so that the binaries can be linked statically and I need not release the object files along with the binary as the LGPL stipulates.

In short: one of the so-called permissive licenses (BSD, MIT, zlib/libpng, X11 etc ...) would suit me fine, but I haven't been able to find an alternative under permissive license.

Any pointers?

Yes, I have seen and read the one answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943058 and downvoted it. The question clearly was for non-copyleft, too. And the [LGPL *is* a copyleft license](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGPL), even if it is more permissive compared to the GPL.

Comment: Did you also look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185568/alternatives-to-gettext ? Namely, [ICU](http://userguide.icu-project.org/locale/localizing)?

Comment: @vladr: I did look at ICU, but not at the thread you suggested. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NetBSD maintains a gettext-compatible library, under BSD license.

see http://wiki.netbsd.org/projects/project/libintl/
it needs development, so anything that is missing you could develop and contribute :)

This should also be mostly compatible with the 3rd party gettext tools and utilities, if you
can get them to compile from source against libintl.